# what locale does wstring support?

Tags: c++, text, character-encoding

In my program I used `wstring` to print out text I needed but it gave me random ciphers (those due to different encoding scheme). For example, I have this block of code.

```
wstring text;
text.append(L"Some text");
```

Then I use directX to render it on screen. I used to use `wchar_t` but I heard it has portability problem so I switched to `swtring`. `wchar_t` worked fine but it seemed only took English character from what I can tell (the print out just totally ignore the non-English character entered), which was fine, until I switch to `wstring`: I only got random ciphers that looked like Chinese and Korean mixed together. And interestingly, my computer locale for non-unicode text is Chinese. Based on what  I saw I suspected that it would render Chinese character correctly, so then I tried and it does display the charactor correctly but with a square in front (which is still kind of incorrect display). I then guessed the encoding might depend on the language locale so I switched the locale to English(US) (I use win8), then I restart and saw my Chinese test character in the source file became some random stuff (my file is not saved in unicode format since all texts are English) then I tried with English character, but no luck, the display seemed exactly the same and have nothing to do with the locale. But I don't understand why it doesn't display correctly and looked like asian charactor (even I use English locale).

Is there some conversion should be done or should I save my file in different encoding format? The problem is I wanted to display English charactore correctly which is the default.

Comment: The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Laurent but how does it help me solve this problem?

Comment: @ryf9059: It gives background information on these types of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug solved, it turns out to be the CASTING problem (not rendering problem as previously said).
The bugged text is a intermediate product during some internal conversion process using `swtringstream` (which I forgot to mention), the code is as follows

```
wstringstream wss;
wstring text;
textToGenerate.append(L"some text");
wss << timer->getTime()
text.append(wss.str());
```

Right after this process the debugger shows the text as a bunch of random stuff but later somehow it converts back so it's readable. But the problem appears at rendering stage using DirectX. I somehow left the casting for `wchar_t*`, which results in the incorrect rendering.

old:

```
LPCWSTR lpcwstrText = (LPCWSTR)textToDraw->getText();
```

new:

```
LPCWSTR lpcwstrText = (*textToDraw->getText()).c_str();
```

By changing that solves the problem.

So, this is resulted by a bad cast. As some kind people provided correction to my statement.

Comment: That doesn't look like a rendering problem at all. That looks like a bogus cast.

Comment: That was not a rendering problem. Unlike MFC strings, `std::(w)string` **can not** be cast to a `char*`/`wchar_t*`. That is what the `c_str()` function exists for.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of code that demonstrates your problem, I will give you a correspondingly general answer.

You are trying to display English characters, but see Chinese characters. That is what happens when you pass 8 bit ANSI text to an API that receives UTF-16 text. Look for somewhere in your program where you cast from `char*` to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Problem solved! Turns out to be the rendering but still your information is helpful. Thank you! :)

Comment: Oh...It's not a rendering problem but a casting problem...just wanted to correct this.

Comment: And actually my answer was pretty good guesswork. OK, it wasn't that you were casting from ANSI text, but that you were casting from a block of memory that holds an object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is type of file you are trying to store text in?Normal txt files stores in ANSI by default (so does excel). So when you are trying to print a Unicode character to a ANSI file it will print junk. Two ways of over coming this problem is:

1. try to open the file in UTF-8 or 16 mode and then write
2. convert Unicode to ANSI before writing in file. If you are using windows then MSDN provides particular API to do Unicode to ANSI conversion and vice-verse. If you are using Linux then Google for conversion of Unicode to ANSI. There are lot of solution out there.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

`std::wstring` does not have any locale/internationalisation support at all. It is just a container for storing sequences of `wchar_t`.
The problem with `wchar_t` is that its encoding is unspecified. It might be Unicode UTF-16, or Unicode UTF-32, or Shift-JIS, or something completely different. There is no way to tell from within a program.

You will have the best chances of getting things to work if you ensure that the encoding of your source code is the same as the encoding used by the locale under which the program will run.
But, the use of third-party libraries (like DirectX) can place additional constraints due to possible limitations in what encodings those libraries expect and support.